# Saving a pem certificate in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, certificate, byte, pem

I need to save the content of a `*.PEM` certificate in a SQL Server database. I plan to save it in a `nvarchar()` column, but I'm not sure what length should I use.

I would appreciate any advice. If you have experience with saving pem files to a relational database that would be even better.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server, and looking at storing something variable length in a character field and not sure how long it's going to be, you should consider one of the `(max)` types like `nvarchar(max)`. There's not a lot of overhead to them, and if you don't need an index (unlikely on base64-encoded PEM!), I don't see a disadvantage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no upper limit on the size of an X.509 certificate file in 
DER.  PEM takes DER and increases its size by 4/3.  So no, there is no 
upper limit on the size of a PEM format certificate.

- Your private key is 512 bytes.
- Counterparts  are another 512 bytes.
- Padding (1 byte for each part of it).
- Exponent (usually 3 bytes).
- The tag required to identify it as a `PrivateKeyInfo` structure
  is about another 6 bytes.

So, that's about 1.1k.

PEM takes this and increases its size by 4/3, which means that it'll be about 1380 encoded bytes.

Add the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` header and footer, and that's another 50 bytes, for a total of 1420 bytes.  (If it's an encrypted private key, it'll be a bit bigger.) There is no upper bound per se, but a file containing a private key shouldn't be larger than about **2048 bytes** if it uses any reasonable keysize.

So, for conclusion, defining the field as `varchar(2048)` should be safe enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's no maximum certificate/key/signature size, and certificates can have extensions.

To be honest, I would follow one of these limits defined by well known companies:

- **Cisco StarOS Release 21.3** (2017, [source](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/asr_5000/21-3_N5-5/RCR/21-3-N5-5-Change-Reference/21-3-Change-Reference_chapter_0101101.pdf)) defines:

  > The new supported size of certificate configured in DER is 6144 bytes and PEM is 8192 bytes".
- **AWS Identity and Access Management API** ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_UploadServerCertificate.html)) allows upload of certificate in PEM-encoded format with these length constraints:

  > Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 16384.
- **AWS Certificate Manager API** ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_ExportCertificate.html)) allows export of certificate in PEM-encoded format with these length constraints:

  > Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 32768.